# Connecting to AWS centos EC2 mysql database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I using the command: `mysql -u rb_remote -h ec2-35-169-41-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p` to attempt to connect to an EC2 mysql db. I can connect perfectly fine with mysql -u root -p when I ssh into the instance.

I am getting a generic error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ec2-35-169-41-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (61)`

Here is what I have done to attempt to connect:

1. In the AWS secutiry group I set inbound rules to accept all 3306 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
2. created an new mysql user "rb_remote" and enabled all mysql privileges
3. in /etc/my.conf I set the "bind-address" to my remote IP address

Does anyone have any other suggestions. I have been stuck on this all day.

Comment: I think you might need to try using `0.0.0.0` for the bind IP address since the public IP address of an EC2 instance is actually assigned via NAT.

Comment: Oh my gosh that worked. Thank You!!